# Why the code I used to load pre-trained word2vec from google news corpus (English) is not working to load the google news corpus (Indonesian)?

Tags: python, anaconda, pre-trained-model

I am working in a cross-cultural language study involving English and Indonesian participants.

In the English participants, I successfully load the pre-trained word2vec from google news corpus (file: GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin).

I was wondering because I cannot load the google news corpus for the Indonesian language. (file: id.bin, file source: https://github.com/Kyubyong/wordvectors).

Here is the working code:

```
import gensim
from gensim import models
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import math
import sys
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=UserWarning, module='gensim')

model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
```

Here is the not working code:

```
import gensim
from gensim import models
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import math
import sys
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=UserWarning, module='gensim')

model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('id.bin', binary=True)
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `load()` instead of `load_word2vec_format()`. `load_word2vec_format` is for the model generated by google, not for the model generated by gensim.

```
import gensim

model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load('id.bin')
```